# ivy archiva working with "latest time" strategy

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, ivy, archiva

I have a system of continuos integration that using ivy/archiva/jenkins.
For a lot of reasons, principally because i work with other people and often we work with the same projects, i have to use the "latest time" strategy for my project's and i use ant ivy to publish/resolve from an archiva repository.
How could i do that?
Is it possible? And if it is, how ivy compare the date between my cached artifacts and the one that's in the repository?

Because when i set that strategy on, my project's starts to continuously downloads every artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have notice that this working, because every repo take note of their modules last date revision, so when you publish an artifact the repos update the date of that revision.